# facebook unity sdk getting the users first name and last name:

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using this -

```
FB.API("/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,friends.limit(100).fields(first_name,last_name,id)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, APICallback);
```

and calling it with this-

```
GameStateManager.Username = profile["first_name" + "last_name"];
```

But that isn't working, I am just getting the first name... not sure if I am doing it wrong or what.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming profile is an array that holds the data, yes?  And you want to concat the first name with the last?

Right now you are only combining the keys together with that code:

(or in other words, your code is really doing this: `GameStateManager.Username = profile["first_namelast_name"];`)

What you want is this:

```
GameStateManager.Username = profile["first_name"] + " " + profile["last_name"];
```

or better yet, using string format:

```
GameStateManager.Username = string.Format("{0} {1}", profile["first_name"], profile["last_name"]);
```

or the best solution, if you always want the full name and never them separated:

```
FB.API("/me?fields=id,name,friends.limit(100).fields(id,name)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, APICallback); // getting just id & the full name
...
GameStateManager.Username = profile["name"];
```

Comment: I tried the "name" and it just crashed.  All of them crash the game except for "first_name".   I will try your first example.   I appreciate your help...:)

Comment: This-    FB.API("/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,friends.limit(100).fields(first_name,last_name,id)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, APICallback);     and this -  GameStateManager.Username = profile["first_name"] + " " + profile["last_name"];    Crashed it.

Comment: Could you provide the code for your APICallback?  You could go through and debug whats the output of the result and go from there.

Comment: It's basically the APICallback from the friends smash example.  I am at work I'll check the logcat when I get home.  Are you able to get your answer to work?

Comment: Hi Jason.  Sorry for the late reply, but I've been out of the office the past week.

But yes, if you use the APICallback from the friendsmash example, you're going to have to modify it to read `profile["name"]`.